# Intel Rapid Start Tech error ( IRST )

Tags: memory, hibernate, intel-rapid-start

First of all, it's not an Intel Rapid *STORAGE* Tech.

Recently, I bought a new Ram(8GB PC3-12800) and replaced it with my laptop ram, 4GB PC3-12800.

When I start Windows 8 (64bit), 
the "Intel Rapid Start Tech." shows me an error message.

[ Cannot prepare IRST space ]

Does anyone know what is happening? what the problem is?
I tried reboot a few times but still the error shows up.

I think IRST is related to some Windows hibernation system. and I actually need that feature.
There is not much information related to IRST even on the Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. The reason was that I had not enough partition size for IRST.

(I think the IRST management software automatically extend the remaining unoccupied volume when a new Ram is replaced, however, if there is not enough space to extend then it fails and it won't work)

So I resized the partition size 4GB to 8GB, reinstall all the IRST related drivers and management softwares, now it works fine.

I think the reference for IRST is quite sparse.. so I hope this solution would be nicely fit for someone struggling with the same problem I had.